# Non Destructive WYSIWYG editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg

I am looking for a very user friendly WYSIWYG for text-areas, that leave the text-area intact, to allow normal JavaScript validation. I have tried tinymce and it is not easy to do that. I am currently using of the markdown wmd, but because it displays in the text-area, my target audience is clueless about how it works.

Any tips or resource that's can help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html).  Here is a [demo](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/wysiwyg/wysiwyg.html) using WYSIWYG.